# Configure MongoDB 3 user roles in SaltStack SLS

Tags: salt-stack

Is there a way to configure user roles with SaltStack for MongoDB 3? I see that the [`mongodb` module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mongodb.html) has relevant role management functions, but the [`mongodb_user` state](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.mongodb_user.html) does not refer to roles anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there certainly is!

You'll want to use the [Mongodb module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mongodb.html), and [execute it from a state using module.run.](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html)

so, for example, if you want to manage the roles of a user 'TestUser', you'd create 'manage_mongo_roles.sls', and it will contain states like the following:

```
manage_mongo_roles:
  module.run:
    - name: mongodb.user_grant_roles
    - m_name: TestUser
    - roles: ["admin"]
    - database: admin
    - user: admin
    - password: ''
    - host: localhost
    - port: 27017
```

The 'name' paramater for the module MUST be prefaced with a m_, so that the state knows to pass this to the module and not use it as the name of the module to be executed.

Also note that the role MUST be of the format

```
["role"]
```

The documentation indicates that, if run from the salt CLI it should be contained in single quotes, like so:

```
'["role"]'
```

but doing so in the module.run state WILL cause it to fail, and return with a less than descriptive error message.

Comment: Does this create a role? Or is it just for assigning a role?